# Problems with speech recognition

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition

I am a starter who is stuck very badly on this initially my main aim is to control robots using speech. Initially I started with making grammar for my speech with this code I was even successful my code is this I made this in windows form application:

```
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new SpeechRecognizer instance.
            sr = new SpeechRecognizer();

            // Create a simple grammar that recognizes "red", "green", or "blue".
            Choices colors = new Choices();
            colors.Add("red");
            colors.Add("green");
            colors.Add("blue");
            colors.Add("white");

            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(colors);

            // Create the actual Grammar instance, and then load it into the speech recognizer.
            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
            sr.LoadGrammar(g);

            // Register a handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
            sr.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sr_SpeechRecognized);
        }


        // Simple handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
        private void sr_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
        }    

        private SpeechRecognizer sr;
    }
```

Now from this code when I speak red , I get red in message box now I want to control motors therefore i need to communicate with my robots therefore i MADE ONE CONSOLE APPLICATION from help from internet FOR SENDING DATA TO MY SERVO CONTROLLER -SSC 32 THE CODE FOR ABOVE IS:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace cConsoleAppMonitorServoCompletion
{
    class Program
    {
        static SerialPort _serialPort;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                _serialPort = new SerialPort();
                _serialPort.PortName = "COM3";
                _serialPort.Open();
                _serialPort.Write("#27 P1600 S750\r");
                Console.WriteLine("#27 P1500 S750\r");
                string output;
                output = "";
                //Example: "Q <cr>" 
                //This will return a "." if the previous move is complete, or a "+" if it is still in progress. 
                while (!(output == ".")) //loop until you get back a period 
                {
                    _serialPort.Write("Q  \r");
                    output = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
                    Console.WriteLine(output);
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                _serialPort.Close();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want like when I speak red instead of giving a text box I want get serial command like `_serialPort.Write("#27 P1600 S750\r");`

Please help I have tried but I was not successful , it is my humble request please answer in more detailed manner , I am a just starter so it will be easy for me thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens? what is the problem? what is the question here? Help us to help you...

Comment: basically he wants the call from his windows forms program `sr_SpeechRecognized()` to trigger an action in his console application that controls the robot.

Comment: Not able to help but +1 for a very simple example of speech recognition that I want to look at.

Comment: @Rangoric - you can checkout my intro to speech recognition article i wrote awhile back. http://blog.thomascsherman.com/2009/08/getting-started-with-windows-voice-recognition/

Comment: my guess is OP has no problem with `speech recognition` as he stated - `Now from this code when I speak red , I get red in message box`.

Comment: @Daniel @Mannimarco Instead of snarking, you guys could've edited the post to make it better.

Comment: @Anna - yeah, we could - however, it was too good not to do this...

Answer (score 2):

Controlling a robot using voice recognition... an ambitious project for a starter!  There could be a million things going wrong here.

Just as important as the ability to write code is the ability to debug it.  What can you tell us further - which parts work, which parts don't?  Have you single-stepped through the code to see what happens and when, to diagnose where things start to go wrong?

You could also try some debugging output - `Console.WriteLine` for example - so we you can see the state of variables and flow of the code as it's running.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to use **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start**

This page has an example - [how to execute console application from windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593313/how-to-execute-console-application-from-windows-form)

`// Simple handler for the SpeechRecognized event.
        private void sr_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( @"cmd.exe", @"/k c:\path\my.exe" );
        }`

An ambitious starter project indeed!

**Update**

```
    private bool LaunchApp(String sAppPath, String sArg)
    {
        bool bSuccess = false;

        try
        {
            //create a new process
            Process myApp = new Process();
            myApp.StartInfo.FileName = sAppPath;
            myApp.StartInfo.Arguments = sArg;
            bSuccess = myApp.Start();
        }
        catch (Win32Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Details: {0}", e.Message);
        }

        return bSuccess;
    }
```

Comment: thanks sir for your reply i have solved my problem last night in 6 hour and my code is working fine now , can you guide me how i can launch a program fromk the inside of another visual studio program do i need to give adress or there is syntax for it thanks

Comment: I added a code example for you. This is reliant on the System.Diagnostics namespace. So at the top of your code page you should add `using System.Diagnostics`

Answer (score 1):

if `Now I want like when I speak red instead of giving a text box I want get serial command` means  - just to `_serialPort.Write("#27 P1600 S750\r");` instead of showing messagebox (i.e. `MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);`) then task is really simple. just copy-paste that code. and  add `using System.IO.Ports;` so that u can work with ports.

so prolly ur code will look like this:

```
private void sr_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text);
            try
            {
                _serialPort = new SerialPort();
                _serialPort.PortName = "COM3";
                _serialPort.Open();
                _serialPort.Write("#27 P1600 S750\r");
                Console.WriteLine("#27 P1500 S750\r");
                string output;
                output = "";
                //Example: "Q <cr>" 
                //This will return a "." if the previous move is complete, or a "+" if it is still in progress. 
                while (!(output == ".")) //loop until you get back a period 
                {
                    _serialPort.Write("Q  \r");
                    output = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
                    Console.WriteLine(output);
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                _serialPort.Close();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException) { }

        }
```

p.s.
if you don't understand how `SerialPort Class` works go to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)

Comment: As niko points out, you can call your code that connects to the robot directly from your windows form. My solution assumes that you want to use a console window to accomplish the same thing. Personally I like Niko's solution better. +1 =)