# Opening new form after a successful login

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void quitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (usertext.Text=="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Username");
        }
        else if (passtext.Text=="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Password");

        }
        else
        {
            if(usertext.Text=="admin")
            {
                if (passtext.Text== "adminpass")
            {
                Class1 class1 = new class1();
                Class1.Show();
            }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

So I currently have this really simple login webform where once I enter the correct username and password it opens up a console application. I'm not really sure if I'm doing it right because I keep getting a build error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace LoanCalculator
 {
  class Class1
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // declare variables
        double principle = 0;
        double years = 0;
        double interest = 0;
        string principleInput, yearsInput, interestInput;


        // User input for Principle amount in dollars
        Console.Write("Enter the loan amount, in dollars(0000.00): ");
        principleInput = Console.ReadLine();
        principle = double.Parse(principleInput);
        //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
        if (principle < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value for the mortgage cannot be a negative value");
            principle = 0;
        }


        // User input for number of years
        Console.Write("Enter the number of years: ");
        yearsInput = Console.ReadLine();
        years = double.Parse(yearsInput);
        //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
        if (years < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Years cannot be a negative value");
            years = 0;
        }

        // User input for interest rate
        Console.Write("Enter the interest rate(%): ");
        interestInput = Console.ReadLine();
        interest = double.Parse(interestInput);
        //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
        if (interest < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value for the interest rate cannot be a negative value");
            interest = 0;
        }

        //Calculate the monthly payment
        //ADD IN THE .Net function call Math.pow(x, y) to compute xy (x raised to the y power). 
        double loanM = (interest / 1200.0);
        double numberMonths = years * 12;
        double negNumberMonths = 0 - numberMonths;
        double monthlyPayment = principle * loanM / (1 - System.Math.Pow((1 + loanM), negNumberMonths));

        //double totalPayment = monthlyPayment;


        //Output the result of the monthly payment
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The amount of the monthly payment is: {0}{1:0.00}", "$", monthlyPayment));
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to end. . .");
        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Wow that is a lot of code, more than what is needed for this question. Anyways try searching "login splash screen in c#" online and you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: What is the build error?

Answer (score 0):

Your winform and console application will compile to separate programs.  If you want to launch the console app from the winform, you'll need to start it like any other external program:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Also, see this question:
[how to execute console application from windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593313/how-to-execute-console-application-from-windows-form)

Some other commentary - you aren't providing any sort of security in front of the console application.  If the winform can launch the console app, so can the user (by directly executing it).