# How to use a C# GUI to call a C# console application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I want to write to applications:

App A - a console application using C#

App B - windows form application using C#

How can I use App B to execute App A?

Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0

Comment: and [how to execute console application from windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593313/)

Comment: Would be probably easier to have a Library C, which contains the logic and you can drive from either B _or_ A.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to open the console app with a button on your winforms app. Place this code into the Button_Click method (or whatever your method is called):

```
Process.Start(programPath);
```

Replace `programPath` with the path to your .exe file of the console app. Also make sure that you place following using statement at the beginning of your code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```