# How to hide C# console on winform before at launch

Tags: c#, winforms, console, dllimport

I am currently working on a winform that uses the console. In order for me to use the console, I must set my projects properties to use Console Application.
[Console Application Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCiS8.png)

However, I would like my application to show and hide said console. I am currently doing this with a function in the `user32.dll` called `ShowWindow(IntPtr, int)`.

My issue is the application now opens with the console first even with executing this `ShowWindow` function in the `Main()` of the active program.

I am looking for a way to hide the console completely until I unhide it using the `ShowWindow()`

Below is a snipped of how I am doing this.

```
#region Console Stuff
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        const int HIDE_Console = 0;
        const int SHOW_Console = 5;
#endregion

public IntPtr ConsoleHandle = GetConsoleWindow();

public Main()
{
    ShowWindow(ConsoleHandle, HIDE_Console);
}
```

This is a example and not my exact code. However it demonstrates what I am doing/trying to do.

I appreciate all given help!

Comment: You can change the project type to Windows Application. Then run the console like answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2593411/1713975

Comment: @CarlosMagnoRosa The problem with this is that its a new process and not the same process as the winform. :/

Comment: May I ask what is the console needed for?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to achieve what you want without using a different process though (based on other stackoverflow posts)

Answer (score 0):

After quite some research, this is the closest I could get based on what you're explaining. This probably has several limitations, for example user closing the console will close the whole app. The idea is to open a console, then hide/show again when needed. This is a `Winforms` application, not a Console application. Here the button opens the console, just replace by whatever code you need to open it.

This works on Windows 10, VS2019, Any CPU.

**Disclaimer**
*I tried to handle Ctrl+C, close event, posting messages to send ESCAPE key, quite a lot of stuff and read some 30+ Q/A on SO and elsewhere. Most of this did not work. As much more experienced developers will certainly point out, this solution is probably not ideal nor robust. I am posting it in case it covers your scenario anyway.*

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WinFormsTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static bool firstTime = true;

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        private static extern bool AllocConsole();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            button1.MouseDown += (o, s) =>
            {
                CreateOrShowConsole();
                Activate();
            };
        }

        public static void CreateOrShowConsole()
        {
            if (firstTime)
            {
                firstTime = false;
                AllocConsole();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), 5);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for input... (Q to quit console)");
            Console.WriteLine();

            while (true)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input != null && input.ToUpper().Equals("Q"))
                {
                    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), 0);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```